# How to use jquery selector on nested html

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html:

```
<select id="my-select">
  <option value="1100">First option</option>
  <option value="1200">First option</option>
  <option value="1300">First option</option>
</select>
```

I am trying out [scraperjs](https://github.com/ruipgil/scraperjs) library to parse HTML. In their github page, there is this example:

```
var scraperjs = require('scraperjs');
scraperjs.StaticScraper.create('https://news.ycombinator.com/')
  .scrape(function($) {
    return $(".title a").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
  })
  .then(function(news) {
    console.log(news);
  })
```

Then I try the same thing on my HTML but it does not work. I only change this:

```
var scraperjs = require('scraperjs');
scraperjs.StaticScraper.create('https://news.ycombinator.com/')
  .scrape(function($) {
    return $("#my-select option").map(function() {
      return $(this).attr("value");
    }).get();
  })
  .then(function(news) {
    console.log(news);
  })
```

What is wrong with my jquery selector?

Comment: what do you get on console?

Comment: you can directly get that all options, why you use that library, is there any reason?

Comment: Obviously, at time you initialoze the plugin, element select isnt available in DOM. Try using dynamic scraper instead

Comment: @A.Wolff is right you have to place these code in document ready or need to make some delay on script so the HTML will load completely.

Comment: @A.Wolff I changed to dynamic and added some timeout, but this time nothing is logged on console.

Comment: do you get anything back with $(this).val()?

Answer (score 1):

You're still using the url(https://news.ycombinator.com/) from the example, replace the url to the html page you want to scrape:

```
var scraperjs = require('scraperjs');
var yourUrl = 'http://www.yoursite.com/yourpage';
scraperjs.StaticScraper.create(yourUrl)
 .scrape(function($) {
 return $("#my-select option").map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("value");
}).get();
})
.then(function(options) {
 console.log(options);
})
```